# ERROR:root:Unable to determine the Neptune ML IAM Role

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-neptune

When trying to run one of the Neptune-ML examples in a notebook instance
when running the line

```
endpoints=neptune_ml.setup_pretrained_endpoints(s3_bucket_uri, setup_node_classification, setup_node_regression, setup_link_prediction, setup_edge_classification, setup_edge_regression)
```

it returns None, and I can see the following error in the logs:

> ERROR:root:Unable to determine the Neptune ML IAM Role.

I guess this is related to roles and permissions but I cannot find anything in the documentation(I followed the official documentation when doing setup).

Question is: how to solve this issue or how to debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely because the notebook instance doesn't have the NeptuneML IAM role parameter set as an environment variable.

Try running `export NEPTUNE_ML_ROLE_ARN=<your neptune ml role arn>` in the terminal of the notebook instance you're using. Alternatively you can add that  to the .bashrc file on the notebook instance.

Comment: This solved it, just wondering where that information is? I never saw it in the documentation when running the setup

Answer (score 0):

Your Neptune cluster should have a cluster parameter group assigned to it that has the `neptune_ml_iam_role` parameter defined.  It is this role that is being used.

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately I have already specified the neptune_ml_iam_role parameter to a group assigned to the cluster, but  it did not work.

Comment: Did you also add the role to the cluster using the Web page console (or the CLI) - From the docs "On the Manage IAM roles page, select Add role and add the NeptuneSageMakerIAMRole. Then add the NeptuneLoadFromS3 role." See Step 3 [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-manual-setup.html#ml-manual-setup-endpoints)